# Or logic not working when there are NaN values using Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, logical-or

I have dataframe `(df)` like below

```
address1            address2            Subject
NaN                 jesicca@gmail.com   Invoice 3
NaN                 NaN                 Invoice 4
rahul@gmail.com     shuan@gmail.com     Invoice 5
```

My logic is as below

1. If value is present for `address1` and `address2` is present then `to_address` value should be Address1
2. If no values are present are in Address 1 and Address 2 or both are `NaN` then "david@gmailcom" should be taken
3. If `address1` value is not prsent or `NaN` and `address2` value is present then this should be taken.

But my or-logic code doesnt work as required. What is the mistake I am making.

My code:

```py
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    subject  = row["Subject"]
    to_address = row['address1'] or row['address2'] or "david@gmailcom"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do it with a lambda function:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[float("nan"),"jesicca@gmail.com","Invoice 3"],[float("nan"),float("nan"),"Invoice 4"],
                   ["rahul@gmail.com","shuan@gmail.com","Invoice 5"]], columns = ["address1","address2","Subject"])
df["case"] = df.apply(lambda x: x["address1"] if not pd.isna(x["address1"]) \
                                else x['address2'] if not pd.isna(x["address2"]) \
                                else "david@gmailcom", axis = 1)
df

    address1        address2            Subject     case
0   NaN             jesicca@gmail.com   Invoice 3   jesicca@gmail.com
1   NaN             NaN                 Invoice 4   david@gmailcom
2   rahul@gmail.com shuan@gmail.com     Invoice 5   rahul@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should simplify your logic a bit (the explanation is quite confusing for me).

Second, what type is `NaN`? I assumed it is `float('nan')`, but if it is just string `NaN` then you need to change `float('nan')` to `NaN`

As far as I understood, it is like this:

```py
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    subject  = row["Subject"]
    if row['address1'] == float('nan'):
        to_address = row['address1']
    elif row['address2'] == float('nan'):
        to_address = row['address2']
    else:
        to_address = "david@gmailcom"
```

So if the first address is `NaN`, then the second one is checked. If that one is `NaN` as well then the default is chosen.